# Problem with multiples invocations of a custom environment

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to use a custom environment command (biography) to create authors' profiles. The code is as follow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{{mwe}}

\newenvironment{biography}[2]{%
\footnotesize\unitlength 1mm\bigskip\parskip=0pt\par%
\rule{0pt}{39mm}\vspace{-39mm}\par%   garantees correct page breaking
\noindent\setbox0\hbox{\framebox(26,32){
    \includegraphics[width=27mm,height=33mm]{#1}
}}%   box containing the frame
\ht0=37mm\count10=\ht0\divide\count10 by\baselineskip%  calculates lines
\global\hangindent29mm\global\hangafter-\count10%
\hskip-28.5mm\setbox0\hbox to 28.5mm {\raise-30.5mm\box0\hss}%
\dp0=0mm\ht0=0mm\box0\noindent\bf#2\rm}{\par\rm\vskip9pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Authors's Profile}

\begin{biography}{example-image-10x16}{Firstname A. Lastname}
includes the biography here.
\end{biography}

\begin{biography}{example-image-10x16}{Firstname B. Lastname}
includes the biography here.
\end{biography}

\end{document}
```

But, I'm getting the following outcome

[image]

I'm not able to edit the custom biography environment in order to fix the position of the biographies when the profile text doesn't fulfill the space around the picture. Could someone help me to change this custom command?

Comment: `\rule{0pt}{39mm}\vspace{-39mm}\par%   garantees correct page breaking` what is the intention of this?, despite the comment it seems quite likely to produce bad spacing, especially around page breaks. similarly `framebox(26,32){
    \includegraphics[width=27mm,height=33mm]{#1}` the image is necessarily bigger than the box it is in (especially as you include one word space either side of the image

Comment: I don't understand the command very well. Actually, I've copied it from a class of another latex project. So, I cannot answer your questions. Indeed, any additional suggestion to improve the command will be very welcome.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You have mail :-).

Comment: `\rm`, `\bf` etc. have been obsolete for decades and ought not be used in LaTeX documents.

Answer (score 1):

Compute a suitable `\parshape` and add blank lines to fill, if necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{biography}[3][]{%
  \sbox\z@{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \dimen@=\wd\z@
  \advance\dimen@ 1em
  % compute the number of lines
  \count@=\ht\z@
  \divide\count@ by \baselineskip
  \ifdim\count@\baselineskip<\ht\z@
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \fi
  % generate the parshape parameters
  \@tempcnta=\z@ \def\bio@parshape{}%
  \loop\ifnum\@tempcnta<\count@
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
    \edef\bio@parshape{\bio@parshape\dimen@\dimexpr\textwidth-\dimen@\relax}%
  \repeat
  \parindent\z@
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \parshape\count@ \bio@parshape \z@ \textwidth
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\box\z@}%
    \quad
  }\textbf{#3}\\\ignorespaces}
  {\par
   \ifnum\prevgraf<\count@
     \vspace{\numexpr\count@-\prevgraf-1\relax\baselineskip}%
   \fi}

\begin{document}

\section{Authors's Profile}

\begin{biography}[height=6cm,width=4cm]{example-image-10x16}{Firstname A. Lastname}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{biography}

\begin{biography}[height=6cm,width=4cm]{example-image-10x16}{Firstname B. Lastname}
\lipsum*[3-4]
\end{biography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanna share the solution I've used to workaround this issue. I've used the `lineno`package, and the code is

```
\newcounter{biocounter}
\setcounter{biocounter}{11}
\newcount\vskipcount

\newenvironment{biography}[2]{%
\renewcommand\thelinenumber{}
\resetlinenumber[1]
\footnotesize\unitlength 1mm\bigskip\parskip=0pt\par%
\rule{0pt}{39mm}\vspace{-39mm}\par%   garantees correct page breaking
\noindent\setbox0\hbox{\framebox(26,32){
    \includegraphics[width=27mm,height=33mm]{#1}
}}%   box containing the frame
\ht0=36mm\count10=\ht0\divide\count10 by\baselineskip%  calculates lines
\global\hangindent29mm\global\hangafter-\count10%
\hskip-28.5mm\setbox0\hbox to 28.5mm {\raise-30.5mm\box0\hss}%
\begin{linenumbers}
\dp0=0mm\ht0=0mm\box0\noindent\bf#2\rm}
{\end{linenumbers}
\renewcommand\thelinenumber{\arabic{linenumber}}
\ifnum\the\value{linenumber}<\the\value{biocounter}
    \vskipcount=0
    \loop
        \advance\vskipcount by 1
        \par\rm\vskip9pt
        \ifnum\vskipcount<9
    \repeat    
\else 
    \par\rm\vskip9pt
\fi
}
```